# Why auto-renew instead of canceling the subscription after free-trial?

Tags: credit-card

Almost all  companies  give you a 7/14/30 day free trial to try their service (eg: Netflix, Spotify).

Some people  forget to cancel the subscription and after the free trial expires, these companies begin charging instead of asking if you would like to cancel the subscription.

What's the purpose behind of this design?  Is it because they want your money and they know that you will forget to cancel the subscription? Or is it because  they can't auto cancel your subscription after the free trial?

Comment: "Is it because they want your money?" What else?

Comment: I once heard that people see "loss" as more severe than winning the same amount. So "losing" your Netflix subscription is seen as "more problematic", than "winning" a subscription (by paying for it). By providing a credit card, it feels like you already made the payment, hence you see "unsubscribing" as some sort of "psychological loss", whereas the opposite (registering for a paid plan), is not that strong.

Comment: Not all companies do so. Netflix for example did explicitely tell me when I signed up, that they will ask me before renewing instead of auto-renewing after the trial month and they did. Possibly its less risk for them than for other companies, because once you get started with a few series ... ;).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The effect you're referring to is known as [loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion).

Comment: Before free trails were a thing, gift cards/certificates were the original example of companies gaining money from their customers forgetfulness. For every lost or forgotten gift card, that money goes straight into the companies pocket.

Comment: "Some people forget to cancel the subscription" This is what the're counting on.

Comment: I once made a 1-month trial on a service  for my father while he was in the hospital, an extra service from his ISP. I tried to cancel it after 2 weeks, and the app told me, no way, you can cancel only it on the last day. Talk about shady...

Comment: Two words: "Loss leader."

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Companies do it because they know you'll forget, and they get money as a result.

You're only getting the free trial due to the number of forgetful conversions they get as a result.

Comment: I would use a virtual (one-time use) credit card number most major banks offer as an option.  That way they can only hit you once for the auto-renewal

Comment: Oh.. okay. I thought it's due to the system structure design or some legal stuff.

Comment: "_You're only getting the free trial due to the number of forgetful conversions they get as a result._"  Presumably it's also to get you hooked on their service.  By adding the credit card requirement it's harder to spoof a bunch of free 1 month accounts.

Comment: Saying "*only* because of forgetful conversions" is too harsh. With decent products, there are plenty of willing conversions which would not exist if you had no chance to try the product for free. Of course, once the customer is signed up (at the cost of giving away service), the company has no interest in kicking them out and making them jump the sign-up hump again. More ethical ones might warn you that free trial is expiring, but you'd still have to actively cancel it.

Comment: @MarkStewart That depends if they are willing to go to court - you owe the money, whether you still have a valid credit card registered with them or not.

Comment: Another reason for getting the free trial is that it bypasses your critical thinking, since people tend to be biased to the status quo. When faced with the question "Do you want to sign up?" a person is much more likely to give a critical evaluation of the service than when faced with the question "Do you want to continue your subscription?"

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't apply to the likes of Netflix but in addition some less reputable companies make it very difficult for you to actually cancel your subscription.  Web forms and emails mysteriously don't work, which you find out when the next payment goes out.  The phone is an international call and they don't answer it anyway.  You may think that you can just get your credit card provider to cancel it but they insist you resolve the issue with the vendor before they will do anything, which you can't do because their business model involves being difficult to contact.

Comment: I think the first line is true, the second less so.  A lot of the reason for giving a free trial is to get people using the service and discovering they like it so the second line seems false to me.  Also to those saying companies make it hard to cancel that's not universally true.  Amazon for example will refund an auto-renewed Prime subscription as long as those services haven't been used since the renewal.

Comment: @piet.t typically the company charges in advance, so they simply cancel your service.  Remember, the first 2 weeks (or whatever) were free.  They aren't charging you for that, they are charging for the next month.  So there's nothing to go to court over.  Not to mention they aren't going to court over a $10 charge, it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: @EricNolan I always pay for these services via PayPal, which also want you to try to resolve the issue with the vendor before they do anything, but the communication is all handled through the paypal interface itself, if the vendor never responds, PayPal will close the case and refund your money.

Comment: I definitely agree with the commenters who say the "only" is too harsh.  Do you really think companies like Netflix would survive if their business model was really built around merely tricking people into forgetting to cancel.  How long do you really think would that work?

Comment: @EricNolan If the credit card company is following the rules, they should cancel the charge as long you have made a good faith effort to contact the merchant, regardless of whether this is successful.

Comment: Not only for this reason. Giving out free trials also allows potential customers to try before they buy. It also allows them to whet their appetite by giving them a glimpse of all the content you have. Its not just trickery (although that is an aspect).

Comment: @Acccumulation I unfortunately have personal experience that goes against this. It wasn't a free trial to auto-renew, but there was a deal for 5 years at the cost of one. Didn't even know auto-renew was an option. Only used the service for a couple months. We noticed the (second) renewal on the statement (missed the first) and the card info the vendor had was long expired. I called the vendor, they said sorry call card. The card did reverse it but later restored it when the vendor appealed with a copy of terms and conditions that mentioned auto-renew. I gave up arguing after a few hours.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I was stating that the policy of "they insist you resolve the issue with the vendor before they will do anything" is against the rules that CCCs are supposed to follow; if you make a good faith effort to contact the merchant, the CCC is supposed to reverse the charges. In your case, the CCC did in fact reverse the charges. That the merchant then re-presented the charge doesn't contradict what I said.

Comment: @Acccumulation I'm sorry I misunderstood. I read your comment as 'If CCC is following the rules, the vendor's participation doesn't matter in getting the charge reversed, _as in the end result_. If per EricNolan's original comment the merchant's business model is based in preventing you from cancelling, it stands to reason they will appeal the reversal (with grounds since the account isn't cancelled). That you can get it _temporarily_ reversed without the vendor's cooperation doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor of course they will.  You seem to be presuming the CCC's will mindlessly get a chargeback with a specific complaint, have the merchant dispute, and follow their stock rules and give it to the merchant. Over and over and over *without ever connecting the dots that the complaints are related*.   Yeah, they will, and the merchant will pay dear.

Comment: You don't get the free trial due to the number of forgetful conversion. Other reasons are: It costs them 'nothing' to give you the service for free, as these services are highly scalable. And it also makes more people actually try their services. Even if nobody would forget to unsubscribe, it would still be profitable for these companies.

Comment: /me_irl: I signed up to HBO for a trial 2 years ago to watch 5 episodes of Vikings. To this day I still pay the monthly subscription. I have yet to watch anything else. It's on my "I'll do it tomorrow"-list of things to do.

Comment: @piet.t: I imagine you only owe the money if the service is post-paid, not pre-paid. A lot of these cases are pre-paid (i.e. they charge you in the beginning of the month) in which case if the charge fails then they just suspend your account.

Answer (score 133):

Yes, these companies benefit from people forgetting to cancel.  However, besides this, there is another reason why companies do this.

One of the obstacles that a business has to making a sale is the effort that is required of the customer.  You can have the best product at the best price in the whole world, but if too much effort is required of the customer to make the purchase, it will be tough to make sales.

In order to subscribe, the customer needs to go find their credit card, enter in the numbers, address, etc.  It takes some effort on the customer's part.  When a new potential customer comes along and signs up for the free trial, they have to go through the process of signing up.  If the free trial automatically cancels a subscription at the end of the trial, then in order to convert the potential customer into an actual customer, another customer action is required, which places a barrier toward conversion.  Instead, businesses combine signing up for the trial and subscribing to the service all in one action.  Now, it requires a customer action to cancel, meaning that there is a barrier in place to discourage the customer from leaving.

There are many people on the fence about whether or not to pay for a subscription.  These people would perhaps decide it is not worth the effort to start a paid subscription, but if they have already gone through the process of the free trial, they instead decide it is not worth their effort to cancel.

Comment: Many people are actually quite happy they don't need to repeat the payments month after month and risk account suspension when they forget to pay. It's like "okay, shut up and take my permission to take my money".

Comment: As someone in the marketing department once pointed out - every time the company talks with the customer, is an opportunity for the customer to cancel service.

Comment: sinister motives aside, some people (like me) are predisposed to maintaining the status quo so if I'm "eh" about a cheap subscription service the default choice (keep or cancel) is going to be my choice. I suspect there is a sufficient amount of people like me to make it profitable to default to keep.

Answer (score 25):

In some cases it is a scam, they never intend to let you cancel your free subscription easily.

Do a Google search to review the cancellation comments about the company you are considering a free trial with.

While not true for all companies, you should always check first.  Sometimes it is by intent, sometimes poor quality control, in all cases it is expensive.

Example https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/lqULU7_dZsc

Consider: If the free subscription was sufficient for you to realize you can't live without it.  They would not need you credit card for the free period, you would be calling them the day it ended, to get it reconnected.

Per comments posted a new related question:  [Stop credit card payments for unstoppable auto renewal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100206/stop-credit-card-payments-for-unstoppable-auto-renewal)

Comment: That's a good point about companies making it difficult to cancel. I've heard of ones that will only let you cancel by phone or even snail-mail.

Comment: Can you cut them off at the source and prevent charges on your card via your bank?

Comment: I think ESR's comment is something worth integrating in to your answer.  In my experience the credit card company was very difficult about this.  They insisted they couldn't stop the payments without the agreement of the vendor, who amazingly was not interesting in doing that (or communicating in any way).  Eventually I had to get my father to cancel his credit card which was after nearly a year of paying for this supposedly free trial.

Comment: @EricNolan see edit and new question

Comment: @ESR I posted the new question.

Comment: I think these tend to be scammers to begin with. I think the OP is asking about all the reputable companies for which auto-renew is a standard practice (e.g. NetFlix).

Comment: @Barmar, that line is rather blurry.  I recently saw a game on iOS that offers power-ups, etc. for a fee.  If you join their membership program, you get all sorts of powerups and daily goodies "for free" (i.e. as part of the subscription fee).  The membership program is advertised in big red letters as "FREE 3 day trial" and in smaller letters it says, "and then **$7.99 per *week***."  My bolding, not theirs.  The reviews cite extreme difficulty canceling the subscription.  Is that a scam?  Not literally, but it is certainly unethical in the extreme.

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, saying "goodies **for free**" when the reality is "subscription includes goodies" is a scam / fraud, literally.  The not-quite-illegal part is the difficulty in cancelling.  The false advertising is illegal, if anyone would choose to chase them for it.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the "for free" part wasn't their wording, I should have been more clear.  They accurately said the subscription included those goodies.  The FREE 3 DAY TRIAL (and then $7.99 per week) was, however, presented so it could be easily missed that it's not really free.  For people who have their settings configured not to prompt for password on every in-app purchase, that could be disastrous (as the reviews showed).

Comment: @Wildcard: Wait, if the membership is paid for through the phone OS in-app purchase system, can't you just go there and deauthorize the charge to cancel it?  I thought you meant a subscription joined externally (website or phone order) which only the merchant can deauthorize (or your bank... for a stop payment fee)

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't know, I didn't care enough to investigate that far.  If you want to, it's Bricks n Balls by "Cheeta Technology Corporation Limited."

Answer (score 19):

I think most of the answers are placing far too sinister of intentions behind the default.  Imagine you sign up for a free trial of Netflix (or whatever) and you actually like it and want to continue using it.  If it automatically turns off at the end of the trial unless you jump through hoops (even if they're easy hoops) then some people will be annoyed by that and never bother to jump through the hoops.  You can imagine someone that signs up online and then puts that account in their smart TV only to have Netflix stop working after some amount of time.  This person just wants to watch a show.  They don't want to go on their computer or phone to sort it out.  The number of people who will never go back and get the service turned back on because of the above is not 0.

One of the more striking place we can see how people respond to defaults is in organ donation volunteering.  In countries where the decision is opt-in the numbers are about 15% and opt-out countries are about 90%.  https://sparq.stanford.edu/solutions/opt-out-policies-increase-organ-donation

Of course organ donation and Netflix subscriptions are much different things but this just goes to show how influenced we as people are to the status quo.  Netflix (and others) have to choose something for the default and it would seem really strange for them to pick the one which would go against their interest.  It need not be the case that they're *only* doing it to trick people into forgetting to cancel.  It could just as easily (and plausibly) be the case that they don't want people to forget to renew.

Comment: +1 for providing statistics on the opt-in vs opt-out effect

Answer (score 11):

> Some people got charged after the free trial because they forgot to cancel the subscription. But... what's the purpose behind of this design?

So they can charge people after the free trial because they forgot to cancel the subscription.

Answer (score 5):

Of course the idea is to lock you in.

It is not only that you might forget to cancel, but they also make the cancelling a hundred times more annoying than the sign-up. Typically, sign-up is thirty seconds on their website; but to cancel, they require you to:

- write a paper letter with a filled form with lots of fields for your cancellation (which conveniently could get lost for more shady companies, or processing gets delayed, so sorry)
- call a call-center, wait several hours on the hot line, and then have to go through a long discussion where the trained agent tries to talk you into keeping it
- other elaborate schemes that are offical 'for your best', but really only make the cancellation so exhausting that you might give in and just pay.

Comment: Popular, reputable services don't make you jump through hoops like this. On netflix.com you click on "My Account" and there's a big "Cancel Membership" button. I haven't gone through it, I wouldn't be surprised if they make you fill out a little survey of why you're cancelling, but it's clearly not "100 times more annoying."

Comment: Or just tell your bank to cancel the payments and let them cancel it for you.

Comment: Cancelling netflix and amazon prime and other reputable services is often just as easy as subscribing is. I'm not sure where you've been getting that from. I've subscribed to and cancelled dozens of online services and never had to mail a paper form.

Comment: @Magisch For example, if you sign up for Pandora radio through the web, you have a "Pandora-billed subscription" that can be canceled only on a desktop or laptop computer. You can't cancel through the app, and viewing the website on a mobile web browser just redirects to the app's entry on Apple's App Store or Google Play Store as appropriate. ["on a computer (not a mobile device)"](https://help.pandora.com/s/article/Cancel-your-Subscription-1519949295562?language=en_US) Someone who used to own a PC but no longer does, or no longer subscribes to home Internet, would find it hard to cancel.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another point of offering the free trial is that they bypass your critical thinking by avoiding presenting you with the question "Would you like to sign up for the normal subscription to our service?"

Faced with explicit question of judging whether the service is worth the money, you are more likely to give a critical evaluation and decide it's not worth it.

However, the free trial is more appealing since it costs no money, so it's something you're more likely to acquiesce to.

When the trial is over, you're somewhat more likely to favor the status quo and thus you continue your subscription... despite the fact you would still judge it not worth the money if you were prompted to give a critical evaluation of the service.

This only works with the auto-renew option. If they canceled after the trial and asked you to sign up to the normal subscription, youre critical thinking would turn back on and you'd decline.

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of considerations mentioned in the other answers: scams, people intending to cancel but forgetting, making cancellation unduly obnoxious, etc. etc. They're valid reasons businesses do this sort of thing.

But those are not the *primary* reason companies engage in this practice. They do it because *people are lazy*.

Perhaps that's the wrong way to express it: a more precise formulation may be that *[default options matter](http://www.nber.org/aginghealth/summer06/w12009.html)*.

Whatever the default is, people will often just do it, regardless of their stated preferences. People are lazy, busy, distracted, etc. The world is a complicated place.

Companies do this because research shows it *works*.

Comment: I'm 100% guilty of letting netflix run for over 2 years not because cancelling it is unduely hard but because I'm predisposed to maintaining the status quo and "10€ a month isn't much anyways." I ended up also using netflix during these 2 years regularly because "now that I have it I might as well". But had they auto-canceled after the trial I never would have re-subscribed because of my laziness.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known in the business world that requiring a credit card up front increases the barriers to becoming a lead (i.e. a potential customer). This decreases the number of leads a company gets, but increases the conversion rate, since only people who are serious about signing up will actually pull out their credit/debit card to begin with.

Quoting this [study](https://www.chargebee.com/blog/credit-card-trials-credit-card-trials-go/), it was found that 2% of website visitors would become free trials when a credit card was required, but 10% would become free trials when no credit card was required. This means that a free trial with a credit card is rejecting up to 80% of the people that would otherwise sign up for a free trial. Further, it is shown that 50% of people that sign up with a credit card go on to become customers, while free trials without credit cards only results in a 15% conversion ratio.

However, that only tells part of the story. While a 50% conversion rate sounds impressive, you have to remember that that is 50% of 20% of the number of leads that are acquired without a credit card free trial. While this study only had a sample size of 100, it suggests that companies actually do a lot better without a credit card during the free trial.

The no-credit-card trials get five times as many leads, and even though the conversion ratio is much lower, 90 day customer retention is better, ultimately resulting in more long term, stable revenue for the companies that do so. In other words, companies that do studies on maximizing profit have to decide if credit cards up front is better or not.

No matter how simple or complicated it is to cancel the account, the point is that credit cards up front produce fewer leads but with a better chance of conversion, while no-credit-card trials produce lower-quality leads but in a greater quantity. This means that companies have to choose on either better marketing to attract more leads, or better lead engagement to increase conversion ratios. It's all pretty complicated, but it's driven by a bunch of marketing research to try and figure out how to maximize profit.

There's no sinister motive in most cases (e.g. making it harder to cancel), simply filtering out those leads that they will have to spend money to cultivate only to lose them anyways. Each company decides if it's more profitable to have fewer leads at a higher conversion rate (usually because cost of cultivation is high) versus having lots of leads with lower conversion rates (usually because cost of cultivation is low).

There's other links in that post above that are worth reading, and with a bit of research, you can see that the decision to require a credit card for a trial is largely driven by the cost of cultivating a lead; higher quality leads are necessary for services that can't afford to give away too much "product" (or service, bandwidth, etc) for free, but some services may find it better to eat those up-front costs for the benefit of higher customer retention.

Answer (score 0):

We live in a market society, where we pay for products. If the products don't meet our expectations, we have a right to a refund. With on-line media providers this is the same. It would be a administrative nightmare to try to refund people for a service they don't like, as a streaming service like this has hundreds of thousands of subscribers. It would cost them too much.

The idea is if you like something, you are happy to pay for it. Especially with financially stable adults with disposable income, setting up an entertainment service for their family without hassle is simple.

There is obviously a 'loophole' where you can get free subscriptions and then cancel. Some people forget. The majority of customers, if happy with the service they are provided will continue their subscription.

Answer (score 0):

A company is offering something they think is of value to customers and the free month is an incentive to sign up and try it out to see if they like it.  From the company's perspective, why would a customer *want* to cancel at the end of the trial period?  They would only cancel if they are dissatisfied for some reason, which the company would like to try to avoid, because a long term satisfied customer is a lot more profitable than someone who uses a product for free, gets charged for the next month, and then cancels, perhaps before the cost of acquiring them as a customer has been paid off.

The company making the offer doesn't expect everyone to stay after the introductory period either, but if they expect more than half of them will like the product enough to keep using it, it doesn't make sense to make the default to auto-cancel as that's not what the majority of their customers would want.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the majority. If the main motivation isn't making more money off of those that are too lazy to cancel, I would lean more towards it being keeping their customers happy and not worrying too much about the non-customers.